# How do I exclude null duplicates without excluding valid nulls - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a SQL Server and am trying to pull certain data. However, some rows pop up with duplicate order #s, where one line # is null while the other has a correct value.

The tricky thing is that there also are other line #s that are null, and if I were to do a filter that `line_id is not null` then I would exclude all the valid order #s with null values. Would I use a case statement? A subquery? I'm at a loss.

Here's an abridged version of my code and what I mean:

```
select
   order_number
   line_number
from table_1
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you; what you describe makes no sense. Also, tab the RDBMS you are *really* using, MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. I have removed the conflicting tags, please correct them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you provide also how you know what are valid and invalid rows?

Comment: Neither a case nor a subquery, or anything related to SQL will help, if you don't know first how to decide which rows are valid. You might need additional columns to define that. Or you might only need to exclude the null line_id's if the order has a non-null line_id - please update the question with appropriate criteria.

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where t.line_number is not null
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where order_number = t.order_number and line_number is not null 
)
```

or with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.order_number, t.line_number
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by order_number order by case when order_number is not null then 1 else 2 end) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```